# Appengine Geosearch results order

Tags: google-app-engine, geolocation

I would like to know if the Geosearch query results are returned in any particular order.

For example:

```
query = "distance(store_location, geopoint(-33.857, 151.215)) < 45000"
```

Would the above query return the locations closest to the store_location first, or alternatively is there a way to specify the preferred ordering?

Comment: I believe that this question provides the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15254983/how-can-i-find-the-closest-document-using-google-app-engine-search-api

Comment: And this is the official documentation that is related: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/sortoptionsclass